# Windows 10 installing Fall Creators Update (Samsung NVME SSD)

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1709

I've just clean installed Win 10 1703 (new PC build)

Yesterday I wanted to update to 1709 (Fall Creators Update)
After starting the update, it prompted a restart. After that, Windows would boot to an error screen saying

"***0xc00000bb*** - *A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed*"

I've found [similar issues](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/08485ba0-f69f-483b-861e-238f161dabee/problem-with-upgrade-to-creators-update-on-nvme-disk?forum=win10itprosetup) on the internet saying that that's just how it is with Samsung NVMe drives and Windows 10. I guess I need to install Windows anew to get the Fall Creators Update.
What boggles my mind is that I can barely find any threads relating to this issue. I mean, the 960 NVMe SSDs from Samsung are quite popular, why are there only a few old threads on the net? Made me think this might not be such a common issue.

One other thing I've found out is that if I restart using Shift-Click and then select "Startup Repair" it'd reboot and result in the same error I get when trying to update.

What I've tried so far:

- Update using Windows Update (Now it doesn't show the update anymore...)
- Update using the Update Utility from Microsoft's website
- Update using the Media Creation Utility
- Also played a lot with UEFI settings (Secure Boot, CSM, Fast Boot, etc. nothing seems to work though)

All 3 methods result in the same error.
I think it might be because Windows can't properly boot into recovery (That's also why Startup Repair doesn't seem to work either)

My question now is: Did something go wrong during the Windows install and might a fresh install fix my problems?
Is this behavior expected from an NVMe drive by Samsung?

My specs:

- i7 7820X
- Asus X299 Prime Deluxe
- 32GB G.Skill TridentZ
- Samsung 960 Evo NVMe (M.2)

I have installed most Asus drivers as well as Samsung's NVMe driver

Comment: The fall creators update is only a few days old, and you're wondering why there aren't may posts on the internet about it?

Comment: That's not it. I've found threads with the exact same issue but from the Creators Update earlier this year. Yet there's barely a hand full of those issues.

Comment: I suspect a LOT of people have these series' Motherboards configured as my "bailout", running IRST.  In particular, if you enable Optane drives, you're "forced" into this config, along with any other RAID implementation.  There are a LOT of these out there, just not concentrated on the 16299 build, yet.  I thought it was odd too though.  I added the NVME clarification to the title, to make this easier to identify.

Comment: [This thread](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?96864-Beware-of-Fall-Creators-Update-with-a-ASUS-x299-MOB-amp-Samsung-NVMe-SSD/page7) has bunch of people reporting similar issues also. I'm also unable to update with 960 Pros, same CPU and mobo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for closure, with the 1004 UEFI update from Asus, the issue has been fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Success/solution!
I have the same system (more or less, same x299 MB and 960 Pro NVME drive).
I got this to work, finally, after building custom boot media, trying some things reported, like disabling SMART, and more.
Nothing worked, and I was unwilling to trash my install and do a clean one, at least not yet...

What did the deal for me was moving the drive into a "fake RAID" mode, by enabling it under IRST.  I'm almost positive this abstracts (i.e. doesn't use) the NVME bus, and then update to 16299.19 (with patch) went off without a hitch, finally!

Afterwards, I "flipped" it back to AHCI, so it could run through NVME and re-installed the Samsung NVME driver.
Under IRST I was getting about 50% performance (50% of the Samsung driver, which gives me about a 40% boost over the Inbox NVME driver), so basically about half-speed of NVME.
I'm set though, and hopefully this will help others that are stuck on the Fall Creators build, with a Samsung NVME drive...
Good thing to "keep in the back of your mind" too, whenever a major update needs to boot minimally, this might still be necessary (depending on NVME Windows integration AND BIOS updates).

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for me.
I enable IRST (instead of AHCI) in BIOS, set M.2_1 slot to RAID as well, but for some reason, the RAID controller and IRST under Windows won't see the M.2 SSD at all. 
So nothing has changed for the system disk. 
When I shift-click restart to open either the Startup Repair or Command Prompt, I still get the same error that I get when trying to install the update. 
Might be an issue with BIOS/SSD Firmware. I'll wait, I guess and try again sometime later.

Comment: Weird, the 950 (or 950) series SSD?  If it won't see it under the IRST BIOS settings it can't do much of ANYTHING with the drive though.  I wonder what's different?  Is your X299 board on the 0802 BIOS Rev?

Comment: It's a 960 EVO, BIOS is 0802, yes. I installed IRST with AHCI Mode enabled and it barely had any settings. When I switched to RAID in BIOS, I had to reinstall IRST under Windows to get it to work. Tried with and without the Samsung NVMe drivers. But yeah, IRST (and the short screen during boot) won't show the SSD. Might try updating its firmware at some point

Comment: You can "transition" to IRST, as long as you install the drivers before you reboot, and force the device to use it, which avoids the reinstall issue.  I'll look into writing up some "addendum" to this, I could probably provide more insight.  If you fire up the Samsung Magician, WITH AHCI enabled, NOT IRST, you can update the firmware, it'll do the whole works, and then just reboot.

Comment: SSD Firmware seems to be up-to-date already. Guess there's nothing more I can do at this point. Oh well

Comment: Are all your (boot anyway) partitions GPT?  It didn't occur to me to post this before, since it's a requirement for UEFI boot anyway.  There are tools out there to convert, although you definitely want to backup any data first (sounds like that drives' data might volatile anyway, right now).

Comment: It is GPT. Should be by default anyway on Windows 10 and UEFI